# How to fetch feed of FB page?

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using graph API. I have to fetch feed(i.e.. posts on the particular page) and display on viewController.

Is there any tutorial which I can follow for my assignment?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get feed of a page and picture in high res with FQL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5498241/how-to-get-feed-of-a-page-and-picture-in-high-res-with-fql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, don't know about tutorials but I recently had to access a page's posts as well.

If you are an admin to the page and it's accessible to anyone then you can just setup a app and then do:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/pageId/feed?&access_token=App Id|App Secret
```

I did this with .Net and a web client request and deserialized the result into objects but I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

checkout this link

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

checkout this example

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample/Hackbook

may be it is use full to you